# Show modal only when form successfully submitted in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I know there are multiple questions like this, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am still learning ReactJS so any help would be much appreciated.

My modal upon successfully submitting the form pops up right, but it also pops up when the form is not submitted, i.e. some form fields were left empty.
I also have user redirected to home page after form submission - modal then disappears by itself.

I assume, having `handleShow()` before try/catch code calls it every time submit button is clicked.
Where should I put `handleShow()` so it only runs when form is successfully submitted?

I tried adding `.then(handleShow())` at the end of `const { data } = await axiosReq.post("/posts/", formData)` but same thing is happening.

My code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

import { Form, Button, Row, Col, Container, Alert, Modal, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom";
import { axiosReq } from "../../api/axiosDefaults";
import { useRedirect } from "../../hooks/useRedirect";

function PostCreateForm() {
  useRedirect("loggedOut");

  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
    title: "",
    content: "",
    image: "",
  });

  const { title, content, image } = postData;

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const imageInput = useRef(null);

  const history = useHistory();

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const handleChangeImage = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files.length) {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
      setPostData({
        ...postData,
        image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
      });
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setPostData({
      ...postData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("content", content);
    formData.append("image", imageInput.current.files[0]);
    handleShow();

    try {
      const { data } = await axiosReq.post("/posts/", formData);
      history.push(`/posts/${data.id}`);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.response?.status !== 401) {
        setErrors(err.response?.data);
      }
    }
  };

  const textFields = (
    <div className="text-center">
      <Form.Group controlId="title">
        <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="title"
          aria-label="post title"
          value={title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      {errors?.title?.map((message, idx) => (
        <Alert className="text-center" variant="dark" key={idx}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      ))}

      <Form.Group controlId="content">
        <Form.Label>Content</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          as="textarea"
          rows={6}
          name="content"
          aria-label="Post description"
          value={content}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      {errors?.content?.map((message, idx) => (
        <Alert className="text-center" variant="dark" key={idx}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      ))}

      <Form.Group controlId="dog_breed">
        <Form.Label>Dog breed</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="select" name="dog_breed" aria-label="Dog breed" />
      </Form.Group>

      <Button
        onClick={() => history.goBack()}
      >
        cancel
      </Button>
      <Button type="submit">
        create
      </Button>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row>
          <Col className="py-2 p-0 p-md-2" md={7} lg={8}>
            <Container
              className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center"}
            >
              <Form.Group className="text-center">
                {image ? (
                  <>
                    <figure>
                      <Image src={image} rounded />
                    </figure>
                    <div>
                      <Form.Label
                        className= "btn"
                        htmlFor="image-upload"
                      >
                        Change image
                      </Form.Label>
                    </div>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <Form.Label
                    className="d-flex justify-content-center"
                    htmlFor="image-upload"
                  >
                    Click to upload an image
                  </Form.Label>
                )}
                <Form.File
                  id="image-upload"
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={handleChangeImage}
                  ref={imageInput}
                />
              </Form.Group>
              {errors?.image?.map((message, idx) => (
                <Alert className="text-center" variant="dark" key={idx}>
                  {message}
                </Alert>
              ))}
              <div className="d-md-none">{textFields}</div>
            </Container>
          </Col>
          <Col md={5} lg={4} className="d-none d-md-block p-0 p-md-2">
            <Container>{textFields}</Container>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Form>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Body variant="dark">Your post is successfully submitted!</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default PostCreateForm;
```

Apologies if the code is too long. I shortened it a bit, but not sure what do you need to be able to help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried putting it after `const { data } = await ...`?

Comment: If you mean inside try/catch block, I did, yes. It does not display it at all then.

Comment: Because you then redirect by changing history

Comment: I tried commenting out the code for history change and adding ```handleShow()``` after ```const { data} = await...```. Remove ```const {data}``` as it is not used without ```history```. It does not work. modal is not showing and I am still in create form page which is not a good UX.